# including citavi "parallel title" feature with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber

This is a very simple question, probably not needing even a MWE - how do I include the "parallel title" field in Citavi in any of the standard style files by accessing the `.bib` database with `biblatex`? The output should display both the main title and parallel title a work is known by.

Comment: I guess most people would use the `titleaddon` field.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an existing field, I guess the most common idiom would be to use **`titleaddon`**. If you like, you can modify the field format so that it comes out in square brackets, see for example [(Hg.) for Authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/458706/35864).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Doi.1978,
  author     = {Doi, Yutaka and Sano, Tetsuji and Tanaka, Itsuo},
  year       = {1978},
  title      = {Senkyo seido},
  titleaddon = {Das Wahlsystem},
  location   = {T\^oky\^o},
  publisher  = {Gy\^osei}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Doi.1978}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: Doi, Yutaka, Tetsuji Sano und Itsuo Tanaka (1978). Senkyo seido. Das Wahlsystem. Tôkyô: Gyôsei.]

---

But you could also define an entirely new field for those kind of titles. [Add field "tome" to biblatex entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163303/35864) shows all kinds of strategies to get define new fields. The disadvantage here is that you will definitely have to manipulate some bibmacros, while you might be able to get away without redefining bibmacros when you use `titleaddon` and accept the output it gives you out of the box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{paralleltitle.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{paralleltitle}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{paralleltitle}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, datamodel=paralleltitle]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{paralleltitle}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\newcommand*{\paralleltitlepunct}{\addspace}
\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
     \setunit{\paralleltitlepunct}%
     \printfield{paralleltitle}%
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Doi.1978,
  author        = {Doi, Yutaka and Sano, Tetsuji and Tanaka, Itsuo},
  year          = {1978},
  title         = {Senkyo seido},
  paralleltitle = {Das Wahlsystem},
  location      = {T\^oky\^o},
  publisher     = {Gy\^osei}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Doi.1978}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: Doi, Yutaka, Tetsuji Sano und Itsuo Tanaka (1978). Senkyo seido [Das Wahlsystem]. Tôkyô: Gyôsei.]